# How to replace the first character of an array element in bash

Tags: bash

I am taking an input of elements from the user and displaying it in a file. However, I need to do one more task. I need to replace the first character of each array element with a dot(`.`) which is unfortunately not working for me.

Please find my code below:

```
while read line
do
    my_array=("${my_array[@]}" $line)
done

echo ${my_array[@]/my_array[@][0]/.}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU bash:

```
my_array=(foo bar abc)
echo "${my_array[@]/?/.}"
```

Output:

```
.oo .ar .bc
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to populate the array first and do the post processing later. While populating array itself you can do this:

```
my_array=()

while read -r line; do
    my_array+=( ".${line:1}" )
done
```

- `".${line:1}"` will place DOT at first place followed by substring of `$line` from next position onwards.
- Also note right way of populating an array in a loop by using `my_array+=( ".${line:1}" )`